# how to pass date in $http.get request

Tags: angularjs, spring, date

i have list of task in my database. i want to filter by date(completed date)
how to pass date with $http get request.i tried some code.it is giving exception.
can any one help me.

angular:

```
$scope.date=1468175400000;
var deadline = new Date($scope.date);
        $http.get(
                '/user/task/gettasks/?status=' + $scope.status
                        + '&priority=' + $scope.priority
                        + '&projectId=' + $scope.project+'&deadline='+deadline).success(
                function(response) {
                    debugger
                    $scope.tasks = response;
                }).error(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        })
```

service(spring):

```
@RequestMapping("/gettasks")
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.Summary.class })
    public List<Task> getTasks(@RequestParam(value="status" ) String status,
            @RequestParam("priority") String priority,
            @RequestParam("projectId") String projectId,@RequestParam("deadline") Long deadline)  {
System.out.println(deadline);
        return taskControllerService.getTasks(status, priority, projectId,deadline);

    }
```

error:

```
Object {
    timestamp: 1468819101831,
    status: 400,
    error: "Bad Request",
    exception: "org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException",
    message: "Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String]… "
    MonJul11201600: 00: 00 GMT0530(IndiaStandardTime)
    ""…
}
error: "Bad Request"
exception: "org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException"
message: "Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Long]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
MonJul11201600: 00: 00 GMT0530(IndiaStandardTime)
""
path: "/user/task/gettasks/"
status: 400 timestamp: 1468819101831 proto: Object
```

Comment: seems like for `deadline` you are passing a date object. Pass this instead `deadline.getTime()` this will send the deadline as long timestamp.

Comment: can u give me the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For deadline you are passing a date object. 
Pass this instead `new Date($scope.date).getTime()` this will send the deadline as long timestamp.

```
var deadline = new Date($scope.date).getTime();
```

Comment: if i right deadline.getTime().the date passing like 1468175400000

Answer (score 0):

From the exception i can see the deadline date is not parsed correctly. From UI you are sending Date object and at server side you are accepting as Long value. Please make sure you keep the data type same at both end.

If the date is epochtime format then first convert like this and attach it to request.

```
var time        = new Date(0);
var deadLineDate  = deadLineDate / 1000;
time.setUTCSeconds(deadLineDate);
requestObject = time.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

Now requestObject is string, please accept as String @ server side.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Is you Server implementation same as   below. @RequestMapping("/gettasks")
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.Summary.class })
    public List<Task> getTasks(@RequestParam(value="status" ) String status,
            @RequestParam("priority") String priority,
            @RequestParam("projectId") String projectId,@RequestParam("deadline") String deadline)  {